# how to use value change listener

Tags: events, jsf-2, valuechangelistener

I don't know how to deal with f:valueChangeListener , I want to select country and the capital appear so  this is my code but it doen't work what is miss or what is the wrong?

```
 Country:
  <h:selectOneMenu value="#{event.country}" onchange="submit()">
        <f:valueChangeListener type="org.jsf.model.ValueListener"/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{event.countries}"/>     
  </h:selectOneMenu>
 Capital: #{event.capital}
```

My Managed bean

```
public class EventsBean{

private String capital;
private String country;
String countryCapital;


private String [] countries = {"Select","Egypt","United States","Kuwait"};

public String[] getCountries() {
    return countries;
  }

// getters and setters
}
```

The class that implements ValueChangeListener

```
package org.jsf.model;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeListener;

public class ValueChangeClass implements ValueChangeListener {
String capital;
 @Override
   public void processValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event)throws AbortProcessingException {

if ("Egypt".equals(event.getNewValue())                  capital = "Cairo";
else if ("Kuwait".equals(event.getNewValue()))           capital = "Kuwait";
else if ("United States".equals(event.getNewValue()))    capital = "Washington";
else   capital = "";


new EventsBean().setCapital(capital);
}
}
```

It doesn't work  ! 
Is this new EventsBean().setCapital(capital);right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Is this new EventsBean().setCapital(capital);right ?*

No, it is not right. You're manually creating a brand new instance instead of using the one which is managed by JSF. Your instance would totally disappear once the method finishes and returns. You should instead be setting the `capital` in the instance which is managed by JSF. There are several ways to achieve this. If you really intend to use the `ValueChangeListener` this way (which is rather strange for this particular purpose by the way), then you need to fix it as follows:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
EventsBean eventsBean = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{event}", EventsBean.class);
eventsBean.setCapital(capital);
```

Easier would be to do the job just in the `EventsBean` itself.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{event.country}" valueChangeListener="#{event.changeCountry}" onchange="submit()">
    <f:selectItems value="#{event.countries}"/>     
</h:selectOneMenu>
Capital: #{event.capital}
```

```
private String country;
private String capital;
private Map<String, String> capitals;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    capitals = new HashMap<>();
    capitals.put("Egypt", "Cairo");
    capitals.put("Kuwait", "Kuwait");
    capitals.put("United States", "Washington D.C.");
}

public void changeCountry(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    capital = capitals.get(event.getNewValue());
}
```

Or, since you're already using JSF 2.0, much better is to use `<f:ajax>`. It does the right job at the right moment. (Ab)using the `valueChangeListener` the way as in your original code is actually a leftover of the JSF 1.x era.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{event.country}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{event.countries}"/>     
    <f:ajax listener="#{event.changeCountry}" render="capital" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
Capital: <h:outputText id="capital" value="#{event.capital}" />
```

```
// ...

public void changeCountry() {
    capital = capitals.get(country);
}
```

#### See also:

- [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener/)

Comment: Can you please provide some input on why using second way specified in your port for valuechangeListener (AB)using is a leftover of JSF1.x era..What is possibly wrong or resource intensive in the second method....

Comment: I meant the OP's initial `valueChangeListener` approach.

Comment: @BalusC thank you so much ,I'm confused about FacesContext,it not clear to me ! why and when i use it